# Syntax error when declaring a postgres variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, plpgsql

I'm getting a SQL error when trying to declare a variable in Postgresql. Check out my code below:

```
declare number int8;

begin
 select ID into number from public.People p where p."Name" = 'Jeff';
 if found then
   insert into public.Friends ("PeopleID", "Name", "PhoneNumber")
   values (number, 'Jeff', '205-123-4567')
 end if;
end;
```

When I try and run this, it returns this exception:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "int8"

I'm expecting there to be only one entry with the name "Jeff", so I won't have to worry about having more than one possible value for "number".

Comment: Hey Colby, these commands are not SQL. You might wanna put this code inside a plpgsql function or procedure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable in pure SQL in Postgres, unlike other RDBMS such as SQL Server or MySQL.

Your code compiles properly in [this Postgres 12 db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4c4e5c90c3878e17dda2679b40f9e395) when I put it  within plgpsql procedure (still, you should consider another name that `number` for a variable).

```
create procedure test_proc() language plpgsql AS '
declare number int8;
begin
    select ID into number from people p where p."Name" = ''Jeff'';
    if found then
        insert into friends ("PeopleID", "Name", "PhoneNumber")
            values (number, ''Jeff'', ''205-123-4567'');
    end if;
end;
';
```

Or in Postgres < 11 with [a void function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=53e80e6b57c63042d9c16c4d4044f476):

```
create function test_proc() returns void language plpgsql AS '
declare number int8;
begin
    select ID into number from people p where p."Name" = ''Jeff'';
    if found then
        insert into friends ("PeopleID", "Name", "PhoneNumber")
            values (number, ''Jeff'', ''205-123-4567'');
    end if;
end;
';
```

You might also want consider this `insert ... select` query, that achieves the same purpose in a single database call:

```
insert into friends("PeopleID", "Name", "PhoneNumber")
select ID, "Name", '205-123-4567' from people where p."Name" = 'Jeff'
```

Comment: Hmmm, although this looks right, it is now returning an exception that reads "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "procedure""

Comment: @ColbyWilloughby: you can see that it is compiling in the DB Fiddle... Which version of Postgres are you running?

Comment: Looks like PostgreSQL 10.9

Comment: @ColbyWilloughby: ok Postgres 10 does not have stored procedures, so you could use a function (see my updated answer). But I would recommend to consider the query at the end of my answer. It does the same job without requiring a function/procedure.

Comment: Was JUST about to say the same thing! Looks like that works! Thanks for your help!